# JAXB returns null for list of nested elements

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm using xml with one element which contains all other elements, all described with attributes like this:

```
<produktyLecznicze stanNaDzien="2023-05-26" xmlns="http://rejestrymedyczne.ezdrowie.gov.pl/rpl/eksport-danych-v1.0">
    <produktLeczniczy nazwaProduktu="Zoledronic acid Fresenius Kabi" rodzajPreparatu="ludzki" nazwaPowszechnieStosowana="Acidum zoledronicum" moc="4 mg/5 ml" postac="Koncentrat do sporządzania roztworu do infuzji" podmiotOdpowiedzialny="Fresenius Kabi Polska Sp. z o.o." typProcedury="DCP" numerPozwolenia="20708" waznoscPozwolenia="Bezterminowy" kodATC="M05BA08" id="100000014">
        <opakowania>
            <opakowanie wielkosc="1" jednostkaWielkosci="fiol. 5 ml " kodEAN="05909991023652" kategoriaDostepnosci="Rpz" skasowane="NIE" numerEu="" dystrybutorRownolegly="" id="2"/>
            <opakowanie wielkosc="4" jednostkaWielkosci="fiol. 5 ml " kodEAN="05909991023669" kategoriaDostepnosci="Rpz" skasowane="NIE" numerEu="" dystrybutorRownolegly="" id="3"/>
            <opakowanie wielkosc="10" jednostkaWielkosci="fiol. 5 ml " kodEAN="05909991023676" kategoriaDostepnosci="Rpz" skasowane="NIE" numerEu="" dystrybutorRownolegly="" id="4"/>
        </opakowania>
        <substancjeCzynne>
            <substancjaCzynna>Acidum zoledronicum</substancjaCzynna>
        </substancjeCzynne>
    </produktLeczniczy>
...
</produktyLecznicze>
```

Till now I've made classes for container element and subelement like this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "produktyLecznicze", namespace="http://rejestrymedyczne.ezdrowie.gov.pl/rpl/eksport-danych-v1.0")
public class ProduktyLecznicze {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "stanNaDzien")
    private String stanNaDzien;

    @XmlElement(name = "produktLeczniczy")
    private List<ProduktLeczniczy> produktyLecznicze;

}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "produktLeczniczy", namespace = "http://rejestrymedyczne.ezdrowie.gov.pl/rpl/eksport-danych-v1.0")
public class ProduktLeczniczy {

    @XmlAttribute(name ="nazwaProduktu")
    private String nazwaProduktu;
    @XmlAttribute(name ="rodzajPreparatu")
    private String rodzajPreparatu;
    @XmlAttribute(name ="nazwaPowszechnieStosowana")
    private String nazwaPowszechnieStosowana;
    @XmlAttribute(name ="moc")
    private String moc;
    @XmlAttribute(name ="postac")
    private String postac;
    @XmlAttribute(name ="podmiotOdpowiedzialny")
    private String podmiotOdpowiedzialny;
    @XmlAttribute(name ="typProcedury")
    private String typProcedury;
    @XmlAttribute(name ="numerPozwolenia")
    private String numerPozwolenia;
    @XmlAttribute(name ="waznoscPozwolenia")
    private String waznoscPozwolenia;
    @XmlAttribute(name ="kodATC")
    private String kodATC;
    @XmlAttribute(name ="id")
    private int id;
}
```

JAXB reads attribute of container element properly but returns null for list of nested elements.
I want to find out why does it happen, and what to do in order to read this nested element properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the following changes:

1. Add `package-info.java` to the package containing your classes:

```java
@jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
        namespace = "http://rejestrymedyczne.ezdrowie.gov.pl/rpl/eksport-danych-v1.0",
        elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED
)
package YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME_HERE;

import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
```

2. Once you have done this, you can change the `@XmlRootElement` annotation on your `ProduktyLecznicze` class:

```java
...
@XmlRootElement
public class ProduktyLecznicze {
    ...
}
```

You don't need the `name` or `namespace` attributes.

3. Remove the `@XmlRootElement` annotation from the `ProduktyLeczniczy` class.

Basically, let the `package-info` handle the namespace. And only use `@XmlRootElement` on the actual root class.

Now, when you unmarshal the XML you will see the element values which are currently `null`.

---

Probably don't need to add this, but: if you want to see the rest of the XML data (nested below `<produktLeczniczy>`), you will need to create those equivalent classes: `Opakowania`, `Opakowanie`, and `SubstancjeCzynne`.